# Insert multiple pictures

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, loops, foreach

I would like to add all my certificates in my LaTeX document as pictures. Is there any way that lets me insert multiple images without captions as follows:

- Each image fits on one page
- for example if i have 6 images and I name them 1 2 3 4 5 and 6 I would like to add them in command like `\Insert{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

Is there any possible way to create that? I’ll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`\foreach` by the `tikz` package will do this. I’ve created a new command that takes a list of numbers (or a pattern with `,...,` in it), and spits out figures that can only go on float pages (`[p]`). You can use the running index `\x` (or however you define it) inside for file names and caption text. The `\clearpage` after each `figure` makes it so that only one figure is placed on a page. You can also reference the figures normally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\Insert[1]{
    \foreach \x in {#1} {
        \begin{figure}[p]
        % \includegraphics{\x} etc.
        \caption{Graphic~\x}
        \label{figGraphic\x}
        \end{figure}
        \clearpage
    }
}

\begin{document}
\Insert{1,...,6}
Reference:~\ref{figGraphic2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you make it center

Comment: yoiu can remove the caption

Comment: I tried to use '\centerline{} ' but still not center it should be above the counter of the page

Comment: @Educ: `\centering` before `\includegraphics` would center the graphic in the textblock. I’m not sure what you want to do with the caption, though. The pagenumber is at the bottom by default.